# Class type redefinition and Use of undefined type

Tags: c++, visual-studio

What is this error "'shape': 'class' type redefinition" and "use of undefined type 'shape'"?
My shape class and main method are bellow, the shape(int si) constructor is just there for me to test my node's traversal though this shouldn't be relevant to the errors.  Any help would be appreciated.

## main.cpp

```
#include "mat3.h"
#include "node.h"
#include "shape.h"
#include "vec3.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Node root = Node(shape(0));                     //torso
    Node head = *root.addChild(shape(1));           //head
    Node larm = *root.addChild(shape(2));           //left arm
    Node rarm = *root.addChild(shape(3));           //right arm
    Node lleg = *root.addChild(shape(4));           //left leg
    Node rleg = *root.addChild(shape(5));           //right leg

    Node lwing = *larm.addChild(shape(6));          //left wing
    Node rwing = *rarm.addChild(shape(7));          //right wing
    Node lhand = *larm.addChild(shape(8));          //left hand
    Node rhand = *rarm.addChild(shape(9));          //right hand

    Node lfoot = *lleg.addChild(shape(10));         //left foot
    Node rfoot = *rleg.addChild(shape(11));         //right foot
}
```

## shape.h

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "vec3.h"


class shape {
private:
    vec3 collor;
    std::list<vec3> points;

public:
    int s;
    shape();
    shape(int si);
    shape(vec3 collor, std::list<vec3>& points);
    vec3 getCollor();
    std::list<vec3>* getPoints();
    void setCollor(vec3 collor_i);
    void setPoints(std::list<vec3>& points_i);
};
```

## shape.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "vec3.h"
#include "shape.h"
#include <assert.h>


shape::shape() {
    collor = vec3();
}
shape::shape(int si) {
    s = si;
}
shape::shape(vec3 collor_i, std::list<vec3>& points_i) {
    assert(collor_i[0] >= 0 && collor_i[1] >= 0 && collor_i[2] >= 0);
    assert(collor_i[0] <= 1 && collor_i[1] <= 1 && collor_i[2] <= 1);
    collor = collor_i;
    points = points_i;
}
vec3 shape::getCollor() {
    return collor;
}
std::list<vec3>* shape::getPoints() {
    return &points;
}
void shape::setCollor(vec3 collor_i) {
    collor = collor_i;
}
void shape::setPoints(std::list<vec3>& points_i) {
    points = points_i;
};
```

Comment: What's the contents of "shape.h" file? Why are several `#include`s done midway through the code?

Comment: This is actually 3 files, I'm not the best formatting in stack overflow, my bad.

Comment: Google "stack overflow c++ class type redefinition" then learn about include guards.

Comment: And what is `Node` supposed to be?

Comment: Where in the code do you get the errors?